# How to convert Array(Struct(Struct)) to Array(Struct) in Azure Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I have tried using the Azure SQL explode() function and it doesn't work for my use case. And when selecting from_json just expects the same structure I have defined in the table. I cannot change the source table structure unfortunately as per design. But, when pulling the data out, I need it changed/flattened.

```
select  from_json(Payload:Employees[*],'array<struct<`Person`:struct<`Name`:string,`Address`:struct<`Line1`:string,`Line2`:string>,`Service`:string>>', map('multiline', 'true')) from delta.`/mnt/empsource`
```

An example of my data structure in **the Azure data bricks table** is

```
array
0:
--Person: struct
----Name: value0
----Address: struct
------Line1: value0
------Line2: value0
--Service: value
1:
--Person: struct
----Name: value1
----Address: struct
------Line1: value1
------Line2: value1
--Service: value
```

**I need this to be output as**

```
array
0:
--Name: value0
--Line1: value0
--Line2: value0
--Service: value0
1:
--Name: value1
--Line1: value1
--Line2: value1
--Service: value1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `transform` function in Databricks SQL.

Here, this is the **sample JSON** string which I converted into dataframe and then into an **SQL view**.

```
{
"arr":
[
{
"Person": 
{
"Name" : "Rakesh",
"Address":
{
"Line1":"H.No1",
"Line2":"Streetname"
}
},
"Service":"value"
},
{
"Person": 
{
"Name":"Raju",
"Address":
{
"Line1":"H.No2",
"Line2":"Streetname"
}
},
"Service":"value"
}
]
}
```

Use the transform function like below:

```
select transform(arr,a -> struct(a.Person.Name,a.Person.Address.Line1 as Line1,a.Person.Address.Line2 as Line2,a.Service)) as arr from mydf
```

Here `mydf` is the view name of the JSON.

Please check these outputs for your reference:

**Data structure before:**

[image]

**Output structure:**

[image]

***Reference:***

https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/transform.html